# Git hub like software for local storage and for large graphic files?

Tags: git, github, version-control, binaryfiles, large-files

Basically , I have tonnes of large graphic files from psd to tiff being a design company . We actually work on each  of these files and keep each version of it which builds up huge inventory. Say for eg . we have a file called abc.psd thats like 10 mb then we do some edit and save it as abc1.psd which is like 20 mb , which means 10mb original + 10 mb of new edits and it goes on till we sometimes have over 500 MB Final files which along with the older version takes GBs of space.

What I understand (being a beginner in coding) from Gits is that it takes only 10MB extra edits and store is as a new version and then call the older 10MBs from the original file. Is it something like or if someone can better explain this.

Is managing files git suitable for me. If yes which software exactly considering the following criterio .

1. My repo are private so I dun want to host in a public repo.
2. It should be able to handle large files.
3. I dun want to host it on cloud. Rather I want it to be on one of my PCs that would serve as my server, thats it.

I came across something called GIT LFS but wondering if thats ok for Private Repo and if its suitable for managing files only locally and not remote.

Can someone suggest the best workflow I could adopt. It would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Version control systems like git will typically store multiple versions of files in terms of differences between versions. For example:

File V1

```
  cat
  dog
  cow
  sheep
```

File v2

```
  cat 
  cow
  sheep
  camel
```

File v1 to v2 difference set:

```
  delete line 2
  insert line "camel" after line 4
```

For large enough files and/or small enough differences, storing on version of the file and the difference sets for the other versions will take less space than storing all complete versions.

Now ... for this to work, the version control system needs an effective and efficient way to compute  differences between versions of a file:

For text files, it is easy to compute the differences.  For example.

1. Split the text file into lines
2. Compute hashes for each line
3. Track which lines have been added / removed / changed by comparing the lists of hashes.

For a binary file such as an image, it is difficult to compute the differences, especially if the image file is already compressed.   Without an efficient way of computing differences, and an effective way of representing them, a typical version control system must store each version of a binary file as a complete file.  This is what happens when you check an image, library or executable into version control.

The other problem with large files (text or binary) in GIT is simply that your local repo will contain a copy of the file, whether or not you want it.  This bad for an large text file, and worse for a binary file with lots of versions.

What GIT-LFS does is to replace the large (binary or text) file in your "repo" with a link to a copy of the big file that is stored elsewhere.  This helps when you do a "git clone".  You don't get a copy of all versions of the binary files in your local repo.  But they still have to be stored somewhere, and that somewhere has to be accessible.

---

> I came across something called GIT LFS but wondering if thats ok for Private Repo and if its suitable for managing files only locally and not remote.

Yes it is OK for a private repo, though you need a separate storage location for your big files.

It doesn't really help if all of your big files are stored locally.  However, if you can store the big files on a local file server rather than having a copy in every user's local repo, that would be a win.  But the flip-side is that it is now even more important to back up your local file server ... because it contains the only copies of the old versions of the big files.

Also, GIT LFS does not remove the need to keep complete online copies of all versions of your image files.

Comment: - Yes this is what am exactly looking at , to host the entire data into one PC  that will act as a server  and other users having access to that (which is what am exactly doing now but without github )  but just want to clear - Would GIT LFS make a difference ? Would it store the difference in versions or the whole files like Github .. And also if you can elaborate on "...GIT LFS does not remove...image files" . Does it mean its mandatory to have online storage or optional.

Comment: 1) What difference are you thinking about?  2)  No.  It won't store differences between versions of an image.  3) Yes ... online storage of all versions is mandatory if you want to retrieve them.  (Unless you have an HSM - hierarchical storage management - system to take care of disk <-> tape migration transparently.)